# How to use authorization in lumen

Tags: lumen

I followed this docs.
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization

Actually I dont know where to define the Gate
in `register()` or in `boot()` function

After that also it say: `Class 'App\Providers\Gate' not found`
And what is the correct one in 3 of these?

> Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate
>
> Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate
>
> Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate

For the 'Checking Abilities', the docs said :
`if (Gate::allows('update-post', $post)) {`

But I cannot use that in my route file.
The question here is how to use gate in route?

Please support me. I'm new with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
you should use this Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate
**remember** everything that you use trough `::` like Gate::allows or  
Route::get or something like that is `Facade` so for import use the uri that 
contains `Facade`
Here is good tutorial which explain how to use `Gate`, hope it can be usefull
https://laravel-news.com/authorization-gates
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/gates-and-policies-in-laravel--cms-29780
https://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/laravel/gates-policies-867
```